# Zend routing - use subdomain/domain as a controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, subdomain

Currently I have such route defined and working:

```
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route
    (
        ':token/:place/:controller/:action/*',
        array
        (
            'module'         => 'admin',
            'controller'     => 'public',
            'action'         => 'list',
            'token'          => 'default_company',
            'place'          => 'default_place'
        ),
        array
        (
            'token'  => '[a-z_]+',
            'place'  => '[a-z_]+'
        )
    );
    $router->addRoute('admin', $route);
```

So the URL in the application could be myserver.com/google/europe/public/list

The client needs two additional options to reach the same page:
google.myserver.com/europe and google.com/europe

All DNS will be handled and Apache will be configured. Currently I have to create patterns to handle these routes, but I don't know how can I extract subdomain and/or domain as use it as parameters AND hide controller/action (make them default somehow) in bootstrapping. Maybe has done it before and could help?

I have created a pattern like that for the google.myserver.com/europe, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem:

```
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route
    (
        ':token.*.*/:place/*',
        array
        (
            'module'              => 'admin',
            'controller'          => 'public',
            'action'              => 'list',
            'token'               => '',
            'place'               => ''
        ),
        array
        (
            'token'  => '[a-z_]+',
            'place'  => '[a-z_]+'
        )
    );
    $router->addRoute('subdomain_route', $route);
```

Thanks for any indications what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, just gonna share if someone needs it. I have created a helper I use in controllers init() to get organization_token and place_path. It pretty much parses different cases of URL and returns paramaters:

```
public static function getOrganizationTokenAndPlacePath($token, $path)
{           
    $url = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    $params = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $subdomain = $url[0];
    $domain = $url[1];        
    $parsed = array();
    if (($token == 'default_token' || $path == 'default_place') && $domain == DEFAULT_APP_DOMAIN){                                   
        // Case http://organization_token.domain.com/place_path/
        $parsed['token'] = $subdomain;
        $parsed['path'] = $params[1];
        //die('Case1');
    }
    else if(($token == 'default_token' || $path == 'default_place') && $domain != DEFAULT_APP_DOMAIN){                       
        // Case http://some_subdomain.organization_token.com/place_path/
        $parsed['token'] = $domain;
        $parsed['path'] = $params[1];     

        // If place_path is not found, try to get the last entered place_path from the database
        if ($parsed['path'] == ''){
            $organization_model = new Admin_Model_Organization();
            $organization = $organization_model->getOrganizationByToken($parsed['token']);
            $places = $organization_model->getOrganizationPlaces($organization['organization_id']);
            if (sizeof($places) > 0){
                $last_added_place = array_pop($places);
                $parsed['path'] = $last_added_place['place_path'];
            }
        }

        //die('Case2');
    }
    else if ($domain != DEFAULT_APP_DOMAIN && $subdomain == 'www'){            
        // Case http://www.organization_token.com/some_param/place_path/
        $parsed['token'] = $domain;
        $parsed['path'] = $params[2];
        //die('Case3');
    }           
    else{
        // Case http://subdomain.domain.com/organization_token/place_path/
        $parsed['token'] = $token;
        $parsed['path'] = $path;     
        //die('Case4');
    }

    return $parsed;
}
```

Hope this helps to someone